# Ruby server and Flash client

Tags: xml, flash, sockets, load, tcp

I want a Flash file to load external movies. Later, I want to add tags to the XML document to control the movies. I have a policy server file "to open a port for Flash client. I also have a file to load, but I don't have a Flash client built to receive the file.

Ultimately, I can control Flash from a Ruby server and talk to it with an XML socket, but how? Here's the methods I'm using in Flash. See document

## Flash Methods "where do I go from here"

import flash.net.*;

it flash.display.Loader;

import flash.events.*;
import flash.system.Security;

## Any suggestions for Ruby XML server appreciated

require 'socket'
puts "xml to Flash..."
server = TCPServer.new("localhost", 8989)
seq_no = 0

loop do
socket = server.accept
while socket.gets.chop.length > 0
end
socket.puts “?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?”
socket.puts “”
socket.puts “”
socket.puts “1.swf”
socket.puts “”
socket.puts “”
socket.close
end

Answer (score 0):

i think you are confusing something, think of flash the same way like you would think of javascript and ajax. you can't actually tell flash what to do, but flash can ask your server what do to next. it also doesn't matter what server side language you are using, it almost always ends up printing out xml, json or html.

Comment: I'm using the "methods panel" and that helps me know where to go next. Thanks